# How can I get tweet having only tweet ID without using twitter API?

Tags: web-scraping, twitter

I have a large number of Tweet IDs that have been collected by other people (https://github.com/echen102/us-pres-elections-2020), and I now want to get these tweets from those IDs. What should I do without the Twitter API?

Answer (score 0):

The solution can be a little bit complex, because the DOM of every tweet page has been made to evade scrapping. In more specific example, if you see the `page source` with right click on the page of one tweet... The result is an empty page. It's necessary to wait a few seconds, wait the render of the browser and next, get the data you want using some kind of scraping after the javascript execution.

With that i said on the table, right now, the solution is a mix of use `Selenium` and `Chrome Driver`. I recommend you to use `By.XPATH` selector method with something like this:

`driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "path to the element")`,

You can test your patterns with a little javascript code on the `Developer Tools` at `Chrome Browser`:

```
function getElementByXpath(path) {
  return document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
}

console.log( getElementByXpath("//html[1]/body[1]/div[1]") );
```

And in the case of that element is a node element, you can extract the content adding .text at that return object in your find_element Selenium Python script.

Answer (score -2):

Do you want the url ? It is : `https://twitter.com/user/status/<tweet_id>`

If you want the text of the tweet withou using the api , you have to render the page, and then scrape it.
You can do it with one module, requests-html:

```py
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
url = "https://twitter.com/user/status/1414963866304458758"

r = session.get(url)
r.html.render(sleep=2)

tweet_text = r.html.find('.css-1dbjc4n.r-1s2bzr4', first=True)

print(tweet_text.text)
```

Output:

```sh
Here’s a serious national security question: Why does the Biden administration want to protect COMMUNISM from blame for the Cuban Uprising? They attribute it to vaccines. Even if the Big Guy can’t comprehend it, Hunter could draw a picture for him.
```

Comment: Do you know how to get content of the tweet by URL?

Comment: give a example of tweet and data you want to scrap in it.

Comment: For example I get a tweet id /1414963866304458758, how can i get the content of the tweet? ( content of thr tweet should be "Here’s a serious ...")

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot. By the way, could you please tell me how to get these infomation: Number of Retweets, Quote & Likes,  Time of tweets and user ID.